# Load filter from path with deepar_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, local-storage, assets, deepar

I need to load a camera filter (.deepar) with the deepar_flutter plugin, but when I give it the path, it automatically adds a "flutter_assets/" at the beginning, however the camera filter is not on assets, since they are being downloaded locally in a specific folder. How can I remove that "flutter_assets/" or tell it that the camera filter isn't there and to look in the path I'm giving it?

I can't use the filters from assets, since the idea is that they can be downloaded remotely, so as not to have ALL the filters taking up space on the phone.

EDIT: I already solved it, I had to edit the code of the library. It doesn't seem like the best solution to me, but at the moment it's the only one I found. Thanks tho!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done such a project before. But tell me, a video might be of use to you. The app seems to be working fine here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QXkv-ts3go

Also, this example may be help: https://docs.deepar.ai/deepar-sdk/deep-ar-for-flutter/example-project/

Comment: It helped me a little, thanks, but he uses another library